# LoadingView in SwiftUI behaves weirdly on iOS 14

Tags: view, swiftui

I am using a LoadingView for one of my views until the data is fetched from the internet. It used to look fine on iOS 13 but now looks really weird on iOS 14 as shown in this video:

[Video](https://streamable.com/wvavlu)

Code of View:

```
import SwiftUI

struct LoadingView: View {
    
    @State private var shouldAnimate = false
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Circle()
                .fill(Color.primary)
                .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                .scaleEffect(shouldAnimate ? 1.0 : 0.5)
                .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 0.5).repeatForever())
            Circle()
                .fill(Color.primary)
                .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                .scaleEffect(shouldAnimate ? 1.0 : 0.5)
                .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 0.5).repeatForever().delay(0.3))
            Circle()
                .fill(Color.primary)
                .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                .scaleEffect(shouldAnimate ? 1.0 : 0.5)
                .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 0.5).repeatForever().delay(0.6))
        }
        .onAppear {
            self.shouldAnimate = true
        }
    }
    
}
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: The issue isn't happening for me in the preview of LoadingView.. so it must be an issue with the parent view that this is in. From the video, it looks like one of the parent views is animating onto the screen - probably because the view's frame isn't the full screen until after loading data. The solution is to figure out which view is animating and call .animation(.none) on that view and/or fill the parent view with blank content while it is loading, so that the view is still shown but the user can't see it ... (Sweet animation btw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The animation looked fine to me until I rotated the phone, then I started seeing an animation like yours with the circles moving wildly.

To fix it, I changed to explicitly called animation (using `withAnimation`) and I refactored the code to make `PulsingCircle` its own `View` type:

```
struct PulsingCircle: View {
    let delay: Double
    let duration: Double
    @State private var scale: CGFloat = 1.0
    
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .fill(Color.primary)
            .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
            .scaleEffect(scale)
            .onAppear {
                withAnimation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: duration)
                                       .repeatForever()
                                       .delay(delay))
                {
                    scale = 0.5
                }
            }
    }
}

struct LoadingView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            PulsingCircle(delay: 0.0, duration: 0.5)
            PulsingCircle(delay: 0.3, duration: 0.5)
            PulsingCircle(delay: 0.6, duration: 0.5)
        }
    }
    
}
```